# How to convert an int to a byte array (which is a local variable) guaranteeing the same result regardless of the endianness of the underlying hardware

Tags: java, hash, endianness

I am writing a method which generates a hash from a collection of Objects. And I need to be sure that, given a particular set of inputs, the generated hash will be the same on all machines, as this hash value is used in a verification process in a distributed system.

This verification procees involves users generating a hash on their machine, sending that hash to a central authority, that central authority then regenerates the hash (using the same inputs as the user used) and verifying that the hash values match.

The method uses MessageDigest to generate the hash. In this method, we loop through each received object, updating the MessageDigest with the hashcode from each Object. Finally, once all objects have been processed, we return a hash from the MessageDigest.

My concern is the conversion of the int to the byte array. At the moment we are using the class ByteBuffer to perform this conversion. The question is: will all JVMs, regardless of whether they are running on a little-endian or a big-endian hardware, always generate the same byte array? or will the "endianness" of the hardware affect the byte array?

I have looked through the JVM spec, and it mentions big-endian in relation to how class data is stored. But it does not specifically mention local variables. So I am not sure if the endianness of local variables could affect the output of my method which generates the hash.

The class that I am writing looks like:

```
...
private final MessageDigest md;
...

public byte[] buildHashFromHashcodes(final Object... listOfObjects)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    byte[] bytes;

    for (Object obj : listOfObjects) {

        bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(obj.hashCode()).array();
        md.update(bytes);
    }

    return md.digest();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, this is perfectly fine. `ByteBuffer`'s default order is big endian, and for that matter, the JVM also uses big endian even if the underlying architecture is little endian. What do you think the trouble could be?

Answer (score 2):

The `ByteBuffer.order()` method allows you to get and to set the byte order used to store multi-byte values such as `int` or `long` into the buffer.

The initial byte order of the newly-created `ByteBuffer` [is always big-endian](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28%29) regardless of JVM, OS or hardware.

Answer (score 0):

> regardless of the endianness of the underlying hardware

Then you are fine. To your question:

> The question is: will all JVMs, regardless of whether they are running on a little-endian or a big-endian hardware, always generate the same byte array?

Yes. The JVM always uses big endian at the bytecode level, and you create a `ByteBuffer` which also uses big endian by default.

Only on optimization will the JIT use native and, therefore, potentially little endian code on relevant architectures; but the "user view" of the data you manipulate will never change.

So you are perfectly safe.

Answer (score -1):

Do it manually.

```
public byte[] intToBytes(int i) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte)(i >> 24),
        (byte)(i >> 16),
        (byte)(i >> 8),
        (byte)i,
    };
}
```

Edit: In the Java language, endianness does not exist. It only matters when you try to convert an int to a byte, and in that case, it's just how your conversion function works - not part of Java itself. Some of the standard library classes use such conversion functions, and therefore have endianness, though - like NIO buffers and `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But will your code return the same byte array regardless of the endianness of the hardware? The point is that the bytes which form the int could be in a different order, so if you access them directly you need to take that into account. Regarding the system which I am building, if a user has little-endian and the central authority (which regenerates the hash using the same input int) has big endian, then they will generate different byte arrays, even though the input int is the same value.

Comment: @user3441604 Nothing in my code cares about the hardware. Eg: `(0x12345678 >> 24) == 0x12`, on any hardware, always and forever.

Comment: @fge The cast to byte then discards the extra bits, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: In case user3441604 is reading that and confused: `(0xFEDCBA98 >> 24) == 0xFFFFFFFE` because of how shifting works in Java, but `(byte)0xFFFFFFFE == (byte)0xFE` so it doesn't matter.